# What is the best way to fuzzy compare two tables

Tags: php, mysql, r, google-bigquery

I have a two tables with ~70 000 rows. Both of tables have a column "title". I need to compare to tables and find intersections of them by title column. I try to use JOIN and UNION, but titles can be little different. I mean, in one table it can be **New-York, USA** but in other it can be **New York Usa**. I googled it, and it calls "fuzzy string searching".

I already start with php, and similar_text, but it's very slow... I think that for this task I should use something else, like a **R** maybe.. I already push this data into BigQuery, but BigQuery support only REGEXEP for search in where statement, or I can't understand how it should be used.

Is R can solve my problems with speed?

Thanks!

Example of `dataset1`:

```
new-york, usa|100|5000
```

`dataset2`:

```
newyork usa|50|1000
nnNew-York |10|500
```

Example of desired output:

```
New-York, Usa|160|6500
```

In other words, I need create new table that will contain data from both tables.

**UPDATED**

Thanks for your answers, I tried R and agrep, it works, but very slowly..2 000 rows in 40 minutes, I have a 190 000 rows totally. Is it normal?

Comment: You will have to provide example data sets and desired output. Otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Yes R can solve the problem. see `agrep` and `adist` for fuzzy search. Try in your own , Speed is another history.

Comment: Fuzzy matching is prickly business. It looks like you may have multiple matches from one table to the other. That increases the risk of false positives. That is because you won't be able to tell the engine to stop searching after a match is found. e.g. 'New York USA matching with new-York, nnNew York, and Newark'

Comment: BigQuery will be able to help here - as soon as you get the ability to write your own Javascript functions within SQL. Soon!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "Levenshtein distance". However, with 70,000 rows, this requires approximately 70,000*70,000 comparisons -- 490 million. That is a lot.

Doing the work in R may be your best approach, because R will keep all the data in memory and probably be more efficient than an implementation in MySQL.

There are ways to short-circuit the searching. One method, for instance, is to divide each string into n-grams (trigrams are typical) and use these to reduce the search space. After all, "New York City" and "Dallas" have no letters in common, so no comparison really needs to be done.

There are probably routines in R to handle trigrams. They are pretty easy to do in MySQL, but not built-in.

Comment: Thanks, it looks that I should learn R, I faced a lot with information, that R is good to analyze data.

Comment: @d7p4x . . . Before jumping into R for this problem, I would first download a Levenshtein distance function for MySQL and try it on a small'ish sample of data.  It might work on your data set and hardware.  Then, look at leading substrings, such as the first three characters matching between to titles before using the Levenshtein filter.  You can probably do all this in the time it takes to download R and configure it to read in the data.

Comment: I try to use R, and firstly tried to create vector with levenshtein ratio for first table. And I got a "Out of memory" error..but my tables totaly around ~10M, and laptop has 8Gb Ram

Comment: @d7p4x . . . An n-gram approach for reducing the volume of data needed for the string comparison function would probably help a lot.  But the margin is too narrow for me to explain it in detail.